# converting normal date to epochtime

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was trying to use a graph plugin which only accepts input dates of format "`1196463600000`" which i guess is epoch timestamp. but my date format is in the format "`2005-01-01`" , I have searched a lot to find a way to convert the normal time format to epoch, bt could nt find any.. is the time conversion possible using javascript ?? could any one suggest a good method to do it??

ive tried `new Date('2005.01.01').getTime() / 1000;`  bt it did nt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two errors in your example:

1. You do not need to divide by 1000 as your graph plugin seams to use milliseconds as input
2. The proper date format is YYYY-MM-DD and not YYYY.MM.DD (hypens instead of dots)

Fixed example:

```
new Date('2005-01-01').getTime()
```

Comment: what if the time I want to take is 00:00:00??

Comment: `new Data('YYYY-MM-DD')` creates a datetime with time set to `'00:00:00'`. If you need a different time the format is `'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss'`. E.g. `'2005-01-01T12:34:56'` is 2005-01-01 at 12:34:56.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
var date = new Date ( '2005-01-01' );
var timeStamp = Math.round ( date.getTime () / 1000 );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
new Date('2005-01-01').getTime()
```

worked for me in firefox.

JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cYQMU/1/)

And converter to verify [here](http://www.epochconverter.com/)